# Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined Angular2 reload

Tags: angular, routes

In angular2 I configured a route with a parameter like this

```
{
    path: 'house/:id',
    component: SingleHouseComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
}
```

When I click house details link it's working fine but when I'm trying to reload this page in this link `http://localhost:3001/house/76887262-185e-4721-a283-6284cab2d7d7` is says

[image]

Answer (score 1):

index.html must have `<base href="/">` before scripts